# Select Option show hide Using Javascript. In the table there is remark column and user need to field by them. But upfront will show text lable

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".accept").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".accept").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Select Option Show / Hide</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1.</td>

      <td align="center">Maker
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <div>
          <select>
            <option value="reject">Reject</option>
            <option value="accept">Approve</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </td>

      <!--<td align="center">ProcessFlow</td>-->

      <td align="center">

        <div>This is Rejected</div>

        <div class="accept"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Remark"></div>

      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

The present aapearing text will go hide and after the selecting from Select option Approve then user input field show to enter remark. So when the select option selected "Approval" then show the text field and user will enter the remark.

Comment: Check out the new formatting of your question, and run the code snippet. The desired behavior that you are wanting is already happening - the only thing I can think of is you are not importing jQuery in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("select").val()=='accept'){
      $(".accept").show();
      $("select").find('option:not(:selected)').remove();
    }


  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".accept").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".accept").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Option Show / Hide</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1.</td>

      <td align="center">Maker
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <div>
          <select>
            <option value="reject">Reject</option>
            <option value="accept" selected>Approve</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </td>

      <!--<td align="center">ProcessFlow</td>-->

      <td align="center">

        <div>This is Rejected</div>

        <div class="accept"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Remark"></div>

      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! for Help, It's working but the current appearing text is not going to disappear when the input field show it's show both of the filed. I wish to have at a time one field. how can do that when one is going to selected the other one goes to hide.

Comment: okay. just add this line $("select").find('option:not(:selected)').remove();  after $(".accept").show()

Comment: Where do i need to add. i try to add this "$("select").find('option:not(:selected)').remove();" code in if section and the $(".accept").show() on else but some how it's not working. Please suggest where i am making mistake.